# typeahead 0.11.1 ttl does not work

Tags: typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead, twitter-typeahead

I'm using typeahead 0.11.1 and even though I set TTL to 1 in in Bloodhound, the list of options to autocomplete on is not updated. This worked fine in v0.10.

What's another way to make typeahead/Bloodhound reload the options?
Here is the code I use

```
var WhtTypeahead = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('pureName'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    //limit: 999, //removed in typeahead 0.11.* 
    prefetch: {
        ttl: 1, //to expire the cache
        url: '/Customers/getCustomers/',
        dataType: "jsonp",
        filter: function (toursAndTemplates) {
            ..returns a JSON here..
        }
})


$('#nameInput').typeahead(
   {
       hint: true,
       highlight: true,
       minLength: 0,
   },
   {
      limit:999, //limit from bloodhound has been moved here in v.0.11.*
      name: 'toursAndTemplates',
      displayKey: 'pureName', //what to show in textbox
      //valueKey: 'pureName',  //the actual value of the textbox (not shown in it)
      source: WhtTypeahead.ttAdapter(),
      templates: { //below is the part that uses handlebars
          empty: [
          '<div class="empty-message">',
          'Type template/tour name',
          '</div>'
          ].join('\n'),
          suggestion: Handlebars.compile(
              '<p><strong>{{pureName}}</strong>{{datesAsSuffix}}</p>'
              )
      }

  }
```

Comment: I am not completely sure but try `ttl_ms`. Somehow it worked for me in some scenario.

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla thanks; that doesn't work for me. Wish there was documentation. Sigh...

Comment: have you set cache to false https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md